# Get and combine multiple json request by id

Tags: php, json

To start, I have two API URLs:
http://example.com/api/list which outputs a list of versions and hash as an ID.

```
[
    {
        "versions": [
            {
                "version": "1.0",
                "hash": "15ac8f7dfcef3f3b9b3b5a48a7bee327",
            },
            {
                "version": "1.1",
                "hash": "5990bf1b3f11225d970c5d266e77e641",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Then http://example.com/api/version is requested via POST that uses hash to pull the version details. In other words, when requested in GET: /api/version/15ac8f7dfcef3f3b9b3b5a48a7bee327 this is the output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Example",
        "type": "version",
        "version": "1.0",
        "file_name": "testfile.txt",
        "hash": "15ac8f7dfcef3f3b9b3b5a48a7bee327",
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is make a foreach loop to read the hash values from the api/list URL and fetch all the version details and combine them all into an array that way when encoded back to json the output would display:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Example1",
        "type": "version",
        "version": "1.0",
        "file_name": "testfile1.txt",
        "hash": "15ac8f7dfcef3f3b9b3b5a48a7bee327",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Example2",
        "type": "version",
        "version": "1.1",
        "file_name": "testfile2.txt",
        "hash": "5990bf1b3f11225d970c5d266e77e641",
    }
]
```

I'm not entirely sure how to do this with a foreach loop since I'm using values from one json request to call an API and get another.

Comment: how are you getting these json responses? Through curl or ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Guzzle HTTP client](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) library to fetch the list, then decode the response body, iterate over the hashes making a new request for each one and append its results.

```
class ApiHashGet
{
    public function fetchAll(string $api) : string
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

        $response = $client->request('GET', "$api/list");

        $list = json_decode($response->getBody(), $array = true)[0]['versions'];

        foreach ($list as $item) {
            $response = $client->request('GET', "$api/version/$item[hash]");
            $result []= json_decode($response->getBody(), $array = true)[0];
        }

        return json_encode($result ?? []);
    }
}
```

Then you would invoke it by passing the API base URL.

```
echo (new ApiHashGet)->fetchAll('https://example.com/api');
```

I went ahead and created a [demo Github repository](https://github.com/scratchers/apihashget) for you with unit tests built on travis-ci:

https://travis-ci.org/scratchers/apihashget/builds/243475865